# Why am I getting an AttributeError when trying to print out

Tags: python, attributes, urllib2, urllib

I am learning about urllib2 by following this tutorial http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html#urlerror Running the code below yields a different outcome from the tutorial

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.pretend-o-server.org')
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.reason
```

Python interpreter spits this back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlerror.py", line 8, in <module>
    print e.reason
AttributeError: 'HTTPError' object has no attribute 'reason'
```

**How come this is happening?**

### UPDATE

When I try to print out the code attribute it works fine

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.pretend-o-server.org')
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.code
```

Comment: Do you get the same error code if instead `print e.reason` you put  `print e.code`?

Comment: @Nick Ok now I am getting the AttributeError no matter which URL I pass in and no matter how I import and use `urllib2` (and its methods). So everything is working predictably. When I do `print e.code` I get `404`. @agf I'm using 2.6.5 and by the way, how did you get `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`. I swear I was getting that same message early today, I took a break, came back, ran the _same_ code again and just get the original AttributeError. I'm thinking ghost in the machine but perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I got the AttributeError was because I was using OpenDNS. Apparently even when you pass in a bogus URL, OpenDNS treats it like it exists. So after switching to Googles DNS server, I am getting the expected result which is:

```
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Also I should mention the traceback I got for running this code which is everything excluding try and except

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

req = Request('http://www.pretend_server.com')
    urlopen(req)
```

is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlerror.py", line 5, in <module>
    urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

which a kind gentle(wo)man? from IRC #python told me was highly strange and then asked if I was using OpenDNS to which I replied yes. So they suggested I switch it to Google's which I proceeded to do.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the error type, the object `e` may or may not carry that attribute.

In the link you provided there is a more complete example:

> **Number 2**

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
req = Request(someurl)
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except URLError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'): # <--
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'): # <--
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
else:
    # everything is fine
```

Comment: right on, I saw this example and just changed the way I imported urllib2 methods and they way I call them (dropped the urllib2 prefix) and the first example works now. See update.

Comment: @s3z: your code snippets are equivalent. It could be a different error. Change the first snippet to print `e.code` to see if they indeed differ.

Comment: Nick, Ahh. I realize that I was testing a different URL before. Please check my edited update. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Testing for attributes on the error object? Really? This must be the worst object oriented design choice ever. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no such attribute. Try:

```
print str(e)
```

and you will get nice:

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Right but how come it works for the author in the tutorial? How come he gets (4, 'getaddrinfo failed')?

Comment: I tried it, and I get `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed` so this is definitely not a complete answer.

Comment: What OS and python version do you have?

Comment: Michał, I am using Python 2.6.5