# GAE '_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'reason'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, urlfetch

I'm using python on GAE. Here is a sample code:

```
try:
   response = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers=headers)
except Exception, E:
   logging.error("urlfetch failed: %s: %s" %(E, E.__dict__))
```

and for some requests I get this:

```
urlfetch failed: '_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'reason': {}
```

There's a similar question from back in 2011 that didn't really solve my question: [Why am I getting an AttributeError when trying to print out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554846/why-am-i-getting-an-attributeerror-when-trying-to-print-out)

anyone knows what could result in this error? I even tried adding timeout to the request but didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this example complete? You have no other code in `try` block? Does exception has stack trace? Can you add it to the question? Are you running local devserver or in google?

Comment: @Alex The code is much more complex than this but I narrowed down the problem to this line, I'm running it on google. Don't have a stack trace, will try to get more information

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
   fetch_response = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers=headers)
except:
   logging.error("urlfetch failed. Status code: %d"  % (fetch_response.status_code))
   if fetch_response.status_code == 200:
       logging.error("fetch_response.content:")
       logging.error(fetch_response.content)
```

Comment: it does not throw an exception on HTTP code status 200, it usually does that when either there's no response hence no status code, or somewhere in 4XX http status codes